# Unable to create a line chart in D3.js

Tags: d3.js, linechart

I want to create a line chart using D3.js. 
[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245) an example of line chart.

This is my code:

```
var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0};
var svg = d3.select('#linechart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', 600)
    .attr('height', 200);
var values = createAxisLine(svg);
var x = values[0];
var y = values[1];
var width = values[2];
var height = values[3];
createChartLine(svg, x, y, width, height);

function createAxisLine(thisSvg) {
    var width = thisSvg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = thisSvg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    thisSvg = thisSvg.append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')');
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([0, width])
        .domain([2016, 2015, 2014, 2013, 2012, 2011, 2010]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, 100]);
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0, 0);
    var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
    thisSvg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'x axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0, ' + height + ')') 
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll('text')  
        .style('text-anchor', 'end')
        .attr('dx', '-.8em')
        .attr('dy', '.15em')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-65)');
    thisSvg.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'y axis')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ', 0)')
        .call(yAxis)
        .append('text')
        .attr('transform', 'rotate(-90)')
        .attr('y', 6)
        .attr('dy', '.71em')
        .style('text-anchor', 'end');
    return [x, y, width, height];
}

function createChartLine(thisSvg, x, y, width, height) {
    thisSvg.selectAll(null)
        .data(mydata)
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
            return 'translate(' + margin.left + ', ' + margin.top + ')';
        });
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) {
            return x(d.year);
        }) 
        .y(function(d) {
            if(isNaN(d.value)) return 0;
            else return y(d.value);
        });
    lines.append('path')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('stroke', 'steelblue')
        .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
        .attr('d', line);
}
```

All the code is in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6r7YbC99Osd1b9kKeU3J?preview&p=preview).

When I run the code, nothing appears, no lines or axis are showed. But data are correctly getted so I don't understand what the problem is.

I get this error:

[image]

I need help

Comment: Have you checked your browser's developer tools?  Is there any error message shown in the console?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Yes, there are no errors

Comment: Really?  I get errors in the console when viewing your plunker.  Don't you?

Comment: @LukeWoodward Oh you're right. But what does **node is null** mean? I edit my main message

Comment: As per a comment on the one answer provided so far, it means you've selected nothing because the element you are trying to select doesn't exist at the point your JS code runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for why nothing appears is that your the code inside script.js runs before the linechart element is loaded. One of the recommendation would be to include your script.js before the close of your body tag.

```
<body>
    <div id='linechart'></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't think this is the problem. I created other chart in this way and it always worked

Comment: @Step This ***is*** the problem. There are more problems in your code once this is out of the way, but this is the reason for your first error as described in your question. Related: [*"Where should I put <script> tags in HTML markup?"*](/q/436411).

Comment: @altocumulus Sorry, you are right. Now I get other problems but there aren't **node is null** error.